# what is active and sequential concurrency in IBM rational rhapsody statemachine?

Tags: uml, rhapsody

What is the difference between ***active*** and ***sequential*** concurrency in state machine IBM rational Rhapsody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, active means the state machine will be on its own thread whereas sequential means the state machine will operate on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks.your answer is quite useful.